# Expresso Store: Can't add/edit product details - Fatal PHP error

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, php-errors

I have v1.6.4 of Expresso Store running on a site with EE v2.6.1

When trying to edit the channel with the product details I get the following PHP error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Store_config in /SERVERPATH/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/libraries/store_config.php on line 12

I also get the same error when trying to publish a channel entry. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've never seen that before. Have you tried deleting and re-uploading all the Store files to your server?

Comment: Just tried that and no luck. It's very strange, everything else works properly.

I did the upgrade back in June and can't remember if I tested the channel entries or not. I think I only fully tested the front end and the store admin section.

Comment: Is there a chance you have a different/old copy of Store sitting in a different folder under `third_party/`? It looks like for some reason EE is trying to load Store twice, which is triggering that error. Normally EE keeps track of which libraries have already been loaded so they don't get loaded twice.

Comment: Yes, that was it thank you. I had renamed the folder store_bak when I did the update as an added redundancy against problems and it was still in the third_party folder. Didn't realise that would cause problems as it hadn't in the past. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance you have a different/old copy of Store sitting in a different folder under third_party/? It looks like for some reason EE is trying to load Store twice, which is triggering that error. Normally EE keeps track of which libraries have already been loaded so they don't get loaded twice.